# How to open the door in the Armory on the Titan Battleship

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

After you rescue Nia from her prison on the Titan Battleship you have to escape the ship trough the Armory where a closed door blocks your way.

A nearby Hangar division console has no power going to it, and if you follow the power lines, there is a switch on a walkway that seems to be out of reach.

I have spotted a drawbridge that is raised up, but have not seen any way to lower it so I can reach the switch to power the console.

Comment: That's actually plot door. You cannot miss it. Just walk whenever you can and you will find key eventually.

Comment: Turns out I already picked up the key, but I just missed the place where the key could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Level 2 Access Key located in the Armory

Once you have obtained this key, you will need to backtrack or Skip Travel to Mid-ship Walkway door where a Defense Door leading to a staircase is located.

The Level 2 Access Key allows you to open this door and gain access to a new part of the Titan Battleship

On the East side of this area, a staircase is located which will lead to the walkway inside the Armory

This gives you access to the switches which will power the console and lower the drawbridge.

Now you can open the door in the Armory.